# Me retorna un valor null cada vez que intento acceder a un webservices .asmx en xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, webservice, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .asmx

Actualmente me quiero conectar a un Web Services mediante xamarin forms y lo agregue de la siguiente forma:

1. Di clic en Agregar dentro del proyecto de C#
2. Despues di clic en Agregar Servicio conectado
3. Despues agregue mi url del servicio .asmx
4. Despues me conecto y me dio el unico metodo que tengo que es el de helloworld
5. Al final se agrego en una carpeta llamada prueba dentro de una seccion llamada Conected Services

Codigo que llama al WS

```
 private void btnEntrar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Prueba.HelloWorldRequest prueba=new Prueba.HelloWorldRequest();
        Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

El ws es generico no tiene mas que el metodo inicial y en cuando abro lo que se me importo del ws me salen todos estos metodos.

Imagen de Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu código no está llamando al Web Service, sólo está creando una instancia del Request.
Por lo que veo, deberías crear una instancia de la clase daleSoapClient. Cuando la crees, debes poder invocar al método HelloWorld, pasando como argumento la instancia que ya creaste del HelloWorldRequest.
Ahora bien, para poder invocar exitosamente el servicio, es necesario proporcionar la siguiente información adicional:

- Binding. Esta información indica cómo te comunicarás con el servicio (transporte, codificación y detalles de protocolo). Esto depende en gran medida de tu servidor, aunque puedes probar con BasicHttpBinding (Mensajes SOAP sobre http).
- Endpoint. El url en que se encuentra escuchando el servicio.

Algo así como:

```
private void btnEntrar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Prueba.HelloWorldRequest prueba=new Prueba.HelloWorldRequest();
        //Es probable que necesites agregar algún otro dato al Request.
        daleSoapClient client = new Prueba.daleSoapClient(
             new BasicHttpBinding(),
             new EndPointAddress("http://.../servicio.asmx")
        );
        HelloWorldResponse response = client.HelloWorld(prueba);
        //response debe contener el resultado de la llamada.
        Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

Puede que haya algunos errores en el código, pero la idea sería algo así. Para más detalle puedes ver el siguiente link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: Resendiz me sale el error System.InvalidOperationException: 'A Binding must be configured for this channel factory'

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta para ese dato.